# Issues of classpath with jdk and jre?

Tags: java

I have some problem like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
    java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
    java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)
    java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
    java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:315)
    java.util.TimeZone.toZoneId(TimeZone.java:556)
    com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.updateSystemParameter(BasicContext.java:824)
    com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.access$000(BasicContext.java:103)
    com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext$ServerConnectionListener.parameterStatusChanged(BasicContext.java:128)
    java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1280)
    com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:240)
    com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:158)
    com.impossibl.postgres.protocol.v30.ServerConnectionFactory.connect(ServerConnectionFactory.java:139)
    com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.<init>(BasicContext.java:213)
    com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDirectConnection.<init>(PGDirectConnection.java:233)
    com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:317)
    com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.AbstractDataSource.createConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:142)
    com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource.getConnection(PGDataSource.java:71)
    com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource.getConnection(PGDataSource.java:63)
    msms.ListenNotify.<init>(ListenNotify.java:71)
    msms.HelloWorldServlet.doGet(HelloWorldServlet.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

with setting the `PATH=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin` and `JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre`. Is is good style to follow.?

Where as with `PATH=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin` only does not seem any issue of ZoneRulesProvider.

Which do i prefer to go with and let me knew about the best and preferred style of setting the env variables.?

Comment: Sorry, not related to your question, but the real question is why you are using JDK 8 in 2020? - i guess you are working on some *ancient* project and not a new one?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is controlled by CLASSPATH, not PATH.  Here's the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html  (Also note that Jar files have their own internal class path and are not affect by the CLASSPATH environment variable.)

Comment: @Leun4m Java 8 is on extended support until 2030.  It's reasonable that some production environments will still require it.

Comment: @markspace yeah, I know what you're talking about. I just ment to create awareness in case someone's freely creating a new project without realizing it uses an *old* JDK...

Answer (score 0):

The obvious reason of NoClassDefFoundError is that a particular class is not available in Classpath, so you need to add that into Classpath or you need to check why it’s not available in Classpath if you are expecting it to be. There could be multiple reasons like:

1. The class is not available in Java Classpath.
2. You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.
3. Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.
4. Because NoClassDefFoundError is a subclass of java.lang.LinkageError it can also come if one of it dependency like native library may not available.
5. Check for java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in your log file. NoClassDefFoundError due to the failure of static initialization is quite common.
6. If you are working in J2EE environment than the visibility of Class among multiple Classloader can also cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError,

Just try to run with explicitly -classpath option with the classpath you think will work and if it's working then it's a sure short sign that someone is overriding java classpath.

**if you can post the entire stacktrace I can help you identify the RCA for this error**

Comment: I have added full stack trace details.

Comment: As you noted in the comments, you are using jre.1.8.0_91. Please try using the JDK itself (not JRE). the class will be compliled and found later on correctly using jdk.